# HTML5 audio not playing with Handlebars templated src attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, html5-audio, audio-streaming, express-handlebars

I'm trying to play mp3's that I am streaming out of a Mongo GridFSBucket. The root of my issue is that I set the src attribute of my audio tag with my handlebars template to the URL that my stream should be headed to but the player is unresponsive.

If I don't feed this URL to my the audio tag and I remove the handlebars code, my browser (Chrome) creates a video tag that blacks out the window and superimposes HTML media player controls in the center and plays the track without issue.

How should I specify to the player that whatever it is streaming to the video tag it is creating should instead go to the audio player?

list.handlebars

```
<script src="../index.js" ></script>


<title>CRATE</title>
</head>
<body>


<div>tracks displayed below</div>

<div>{{userNameId}}'s Tracks</div>

{{#each tracks}}
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <form id="trackSelection" method="GET" action="/play">
        <input type="hidden" name="bytes" value="{{length}}">
         <button class="playButton" type="submit" name="id" value=" . 
         {{_id}}">{{filename}}</button>
        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}


  <audio  id="playback" src="{{sourceUrl}}" type="audio/mpeg" controls> 
  </audio>

  </body>
  </html>
```

index.js

```
app.get('/play', urlEditor, function(req, res, next) {

var db = req.db // => Db object
var size = sanitizer.escape(req.query.bytes);
var sanitizedTrackId = sanitizer.escape(req.query.id);
var username = 'ross';

var protocol = req.protocol;
var originalUrl = req.originalUrl;

// var sourceUrl = protocol + '://' + hosted + originalUrl;
var sourceUrl = protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + originalUrl;

console.log("sourceUrl", sourceUrl)
console.log("type", typeof sourceUrl)

if (username) {
    const collection = db.collection(username + ".files");
    var userNameId = collection.s.name;
    console.log(userNameId);

    const tracks = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, tracks) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            // return tracks;
            finishPage(tracks);
        }))
    })


} else {

    console.log('waiting')

}

function finishPage(tracks) {


    try {

        console.log("SID", sanitizedTrackId);
        var trackID = new ObjectID(sanitizedTrackId);

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid trackID in URL parameter. Must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" });
    }
    let playEngine = new mongo.GridFSBucket(db, {

        bucketName: username

    });

    var downloadStream = playEngine.openDownloadStream(trackID);
    downloadStream.pipe(res);

    console.log('success');
    console.log("___________________");

    var head = {
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
        'Content-Length': size,
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3',
    }

    // res.render("list");
    // res.set({ 'content-type': 'audio/mp3', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-length': size }).render("list", { tracks: tracks, userNameId: userNameId, sourceUrl: sourceUrl });

    res.status(206, head).render("list", { tracks: tracks, userNameId: userNameId, sourceUrl: sourceUrl });

}
```

Comment: That's not how you access content stored with GridFS. All you are doing here is returning the "documents" containing the contents via a regular `collection.find()`. There are actually methods like [`openDownloadStream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/GridFSBucket.html#openDownloadStream) and others which gather the chunks and assemble for you. But you do not "render" that content in a template. Instead the server needs an endpoint which "looks like a file" which you point at with a regular url so the browser fetches that content.

Comment: the collection.find is there to pull things like id, filename and length for handlebars to have when it re-renders the page after the 'openDownloadStream()' is started. I did this because the src attribute can only be assigned once, when the page is loaded. But right above where I have console.log("success") is where I'm opening the download stream, filtering my search with a 'trackID', and then piping that to res. I chose not to use fs  ("potentially something that "looks like a file"?) because I've read that could be memory-intensive.

Comment: You're doing more than just a couple of things wrong here, and a complete tutorial is a bit beyond the scope of answers on this site, therefore I'm trying to "point you in the right direction". There is no point thinking about things like "memory intensive" when you still have the basics wrong. There are more than a few examples of returning a "file like response" as an endpoint you can indeed follow if you look for them.